# Поиск нужних символов в кортеже: найти строку длиной в 1 символ, который будет в string.ascii_letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как найти букву в tuple в одну строку?

```
a = (1, 'b')
letter = 'нужний код'
print(letter)
'b'
```

Мне нужна только буква, но если кто-то напишет не только для букв ето может помочь другим)

Comment: нужно найти строку длинной в 1 символ которий будет в string.ascii_letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто найти все объекты-строки (одиночных символов в Python нет) в  внутри `tuple` (вообще внутри любого итерируемого объекта):

```
a = (1, 'b', 2, 'x', 'y')
s = [item for item in a if isinstance(item, str)]
print(s)  # ['b', 'x', 'y']
```

Найти только первый объект-строку без формирования полного списка:

```
a = (1, 'b', 2, 'x', 'y')
letter = next(item for item in a if isinstance(item, str))
print(letter)  # b
```

Comment: а именно букву найти?чтоб к примеру item in string.ascii_lowercase = True виполнялась?next тут вроде не подойдет(или я криво написал)

Comment: @lalalala, буквы в верхнем регистре - тоже буквы. А вообще, достаточно дополнить условие в if: `if isinstance(item, str) and item.islower()`. next  у меня прекрасно работает.

Comment: ну просто можно перевести все в нижний и искать по нему
просто как я понял первий код может присвоить letter к примеру '1245' поетому нужно ещо условие item.islower()
спасибо

Comment: @lalalala, тогда вам нужно `item.isalpha()`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import string
>>> t = 1, 'b'
>>> next(s for s in t if isinstance(s, str) and s in string.ascii_letters and len(s) == 1)
'b'
```